# Javascript how to use modules to Import/Export all from file?

Tags: javascript

With this code I am able to successfully import / access variables and functions when they are individually exported, but I want to be able to export the entire file in a single declaration. I've tried a number of variations from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) but cannot achieve this.

**script.js**

```
import * as testImport from './test.js';

console.log( testImport.testVar ); // Returns 'Test Variable'
console.log( testImport.testFunc() ); // Returns 'Test Function'
```

**test.js**

```
export let testVar = 'Test Variable';

export function testFunc() {
    return 'Test Function';
}
```

**desired ( without individual 'exports' )**

```
let testVar = 'Test Variable';

function testFunc() {
    return 'Test Function';
}

export * // ?
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "all from file"? I understand the description of your problem as "How do you export in a single statement instead of in individual statements?" Though well [explained on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), I see why this can be confusing.

Comment: I'm still familiarizing myself with the correct usage of modules so really was just exploring whether they can be used in the same way an ajax or getscript request would be, but as mentioned below this isn't what they're meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing like you ask for, because it conflicts diametrically with the intention behind modules.

The **whole point of modules is to keep all variables private to the module** with the *exception of making those **explicitly exported** available for **importing***.

Comment: I'll add for anyone looking for this functionality, this is covered comprehensively here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: You think your question is a candidate for being a duplicate to that question?

Comment: I don't think so since it pertains specifically to the usage of modules, albeit as you say their function is different to what I am after. Appreciate your clarification on this - thanks!